# Why I am getting DatasetV1Adapter return type instead of TensorSliceDataset for tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I was just following code samples in the Book "Hands on Machine Learning with scikit-learn and tensorflow".

```
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.range(10)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X)
```

According to the book I should get type of variable 'dataset' 'TensorSliceDataset shapes:(), types: tf.int32', but instead I am getting 'DatasetV1Adapter shapes: (), types: tf.int32'

Comment: I'm finding the same thing.  I'm using a simple `TFRecordDataset()` pipeline and, while the `TFRecordDataset()` constructor does return a `TFRecordDataset` object, as soon as I apply the `map()` operation, I start getting `DatasetV1Adapter` as the resulting object for all remaining results. Not sure why it does, but it seems normal.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with tf version 1.14.0.
`<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: (), types: tf.int32>`

Comment: You need to suggest the tensorflow version number you are using. The newer releases show proper data type.

Comment: same issue with tf.data.Dataset.list_files(). I get a <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: (), types: tf.string>. Using TensorFlow 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on their documentation, if you're using tf 2.0 (or below) it doesn't support TensorSliceDataset, and will give you DatasetV1Adapter
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops

You will need TF 2.1.x and up

Comment: Is there documentation for `DatasetV1Adapter`? I wasn't able to find it

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a different TensorFlow version than the one used in the book. I encountered a similar issue running [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/load_data/images.ipynb#scrollTo=coORvEH-NGwc) and compared to my locally running machine until I installed the latest version of TensorFlow using pip and not the anaconda version.